# Opening a Blank Layout Makes the App crash

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am creating an app and added a new Resource Layout File. In Android Studio Preview, I am able to preview the file. The problem is that, While Calling that Layout, the app is getting crashed.

details_main_xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
</LinearLayout>
```

DetailsMain.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
public class DetailsMain extends AppCompatActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.details_main);
    }
}
```

I am calling this Activity fron Navigation bar Menu Item. The code is as follows.

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_details) {
        Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DetailsMain.class);
            startActivity(in);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
        }
```

What Mistake had I made?

LogCat

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   Process: switchmode.new.switch, PID: 3156
>                                                                                   android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {switchmode.new.switch/switchmode.new.switch.DetailsMain}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1777)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1501)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:843)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984)
>                                                                                       at
>   switchmode.new.switch.MainActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:97)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:151)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
>                                                                                       at
>   android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:318)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4789)
>                                                                                       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19881)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                       at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)

Comment: please post logcat?

Comment: What error you getting?

Comment: what is the exception ? post here the crash log

Answer (score 1):

You forget to Declare your Activity in manifest file.

```
  <activity android:name="your.pakage.name.DetailsMain" />
```

Comment: Hi Sohail. i have a doubt, Do we need to Declare all activities in the Manifest???

Comment: yes all activities must have to be declare in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

you need to declare `DetailsMain` in your `Manifest` file

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <activity 
       android:name="com.example.DetailsMain"/>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't declared activity in menifest file

```
<activity android:name="you_package_name.DetailsMain" />
```